# PDF does not reload on directory browsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, pdf

Hi guys this is my follow up question and I think this is the real issue here. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641904/how-to-render-rdlc-to-pdf-in-ie-and-opera)

Whenever I access the file using the directory browsing (eg. `http://localhost/temp/1.pdf`) it always render the old or previous PDF file even if I change the entire file with the same file name, example I have 1.pdf with some content then I delete this file on the directory then replace with new and different content and rename it to 1.pdf then when I access it using browser it always render the previous value not the new one that I replace. This only happens on IE and Opera browser. Please need help this is a production issue.

Edit:
I found something very strange, example i have this url for the location of the pdf file (eg. `http://localhost/website/tempfolder/1.pdf`) the first pdf that I generated will show then some part in my code I change the casing of some letter example 't', I change it to 'T' then the newly pdf shows but when I revert back to the old case expecting that it will show the new pdf but sad to say the first PDF file shows.

Comment: What happens if you restart the web server in between the calls (just for testing purposes)?

Comment: Might also be worth checking that the browser isn't caching it. Check under Browsing history Settings, and perhaps try selecting `Every time I visit the webpage`. I know this has fixed weird behaviour for me before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is probably caching the PDF files.

For IE, you can do a CTRL F5 to force it to reload from web server.
Or put a random query string in your URL 
e.g. /temp/1.pdf?v=1, /temp/1.pdf?v=2

Assuming you server is IIS, permanent solution is to configure HTTP response headers.

Go to IIS manager

Navigate to your folder

Click "HTTP Response Headers" in Features View

Right-button click/select "Set Common Headers"

Check "Expire Web Content" and select "Immediately".